# Tomcat - Error creating bean with name entityManagerFactory

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, tomcat, cas

I'm working on RHEL6 with a Jasig CAS 3.5.2.1 implementation using a Maven 2.2.1 overlay with Apache Tomcat 7.0.54 and an Oracle database for LDAP authentication and I'm having some trouble making Tomcat play nice with the database. When I start up Tomcat and attempt to log in to CAS, I get a 404 message and when I checked the Tomcat localhost logs all it said was:

```
Jun 11, 2014 10:40:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: SafeContextLoaderListener: 
The Spring ContextLoaderListener we wrap threw on contextInitialized.
But for our having caught this error, the web application context would not have initialized.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ticketRegistry': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-con
figuration/ticketRegistry.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:342)
    .
    .
    .
    .
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sp
ring-configuration/ticketRegistry.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
... 42 more
```

My entityFactoryManager bean looks like:

```
<!-- Ticket Registry -->
 <bean id="ticketRegistry" class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JpaTicketRegistry" />

<!-- 
 Injects EntityManager/Factory instances into beans with
 @PersistenceUnit and @PersistenceContext
-->
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

   <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
     class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
       <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
           <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
           <property name="showSql" value="true" />
           <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
         </bean>
       </property>
     <property name="jpaProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
       </props>
     </property>
 </bean>
```

Where database.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect.

I've tried a few things I've seen around here and the web, but nothing has quite managed to clear up my confusion on this matter. I'd appreciate any help I can get on this.

Thank you for your time.